# AVAssetExportSession fails in compiling .mp4 video and .aac audio together on iOS13 device

Tags: ios, avfoundation, media, avasset

Some of my code for combining an .mp4 and an .aac file together into an .mov file worked just fine since its very beginning. However, after I upgraded my devices to iOS13(beta), it always ends up with .failed status and an Error object.

My function creats an AVMutableComposition with 1 video track and 1 audio track from the input audio and video files. After exportAsynchronously(),  the AVAssetExportSession instance's status becomes AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed successfully. But on iOS13 devices it always becomes AVAssetExportSession.Status.failed, and the AVAssetExportSession.error reads:

Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12735), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x2815e9bc0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12735 "(null)”}}

I've tested this on iPhone6Plus and iPhone7, both given the same result.

```
func compileAudioAndVideoToMovie(audioInputURL:URL, videoInputURL:URL) {   
        let docPath:String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];   
        let videoOutputURL:URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: docPath).appendingPathComponent("video_output.mov");   
        do   
        {   
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: videoOutputURL);   
        }   
        catch {}   
        let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition();   
        let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid);   
        let videoInputAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoInputURL);   
        let audioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid);   
        let audioInputAsset = AVURLAsset(url: audioInputURL);   
        do   
        {   
            try videoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1000), duration: CMTimeMake(value: 3000, timescale: 1000)), of: videoInputAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0], at: CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1000));// Insert an 3-second video clip into the video track   
            try audioTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1000), duration: CMTimeMake(value: 3000, timescale: 1000)), of: audioInputAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)[0], at: CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1000));// Insert an 3-second audio clip into the audio track   

            let assetExporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough);   
            assetExporter?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov;   
            assetExporter?.outputURL = videoOutputURL;   
            assetExporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = false;   
            assetExporter?.exportAsynchronously {   
                switch (assetExporter?.status)   
                {   
                case .cancelled:   
                    print("Exporting cancelled");   
                case .completed:   
                    print("Exporting completed");   
                case .exporting:   
                    print("Exporting ...");   
                case .failed:   
                    print("Exporting failed");   
                default:   
                    print("Exporting with other result");   
                }   
                if let error = assetExporter?.error   
                {   
                    print("Error:\n\(error)");   
                }   
            }   
        }   
        catch   
        {   
            print("Exception when compiling movie");   
        }   
    }
```

You can clone my minimal demo project with sample input audio and video files embedded in its bundle from here:https://github.com/chenqiu1024/iOS13VideoRecordingError.git 
, run it and check the console output.

Is there any explanation or suggestion?

Comment: The sample worked on pre iOS13 on an iPhone X & a 6s - I don't have iOS 13 installed anywhere. I associate `kCMSampleBufferError_BufferHasNoSampleSizes = -12735` with creating/copying audio `CMSampleBuffer`s when the format is wrong  (could be video too!) but your audio looks fine.

Comment: Hey man you ever come up with anything? This is exactly my issue to at the moment, IOS 13 as well. Muxing AAC and MP4 into another MP4 (you're doing a MOV here but still).

Comment: I'm getting the same issue on iOS13 now. Anybody managed to get this working?

Comment: Same here cropping an mp4 video used to work fine pre iOS13 and now just a blank video